# JSONConverter.bas throws compile error: Sub or Function not defined

Tags: excel, vba, hjson

Windows 10
Excel O365 VBA
Imported Jsonconverter.bas into project Modulels
Imported Dictionary.cls into Project Class
Reference added for MS Runtime scripting

I can see data in my .ResponseText, but as soon as the program calls
`Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)`,
I get the compile error.

Do I need to do anything with the Dictionary other than importing it into the Class section? Is there ANY reference to it in the main sub of my script?

The code is below. Error Function is below that and `http.responsetext` is below that.

```
Sub getdata()

Dim inJson As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim http As Object
Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")
Url = "https://www.printavo.com/api/v1/orders?email=mysite.com&token=UN" & "&query=1005"
http.Open "Get", Url, False
http.send
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)
Stop: 'never makes it here!
.
.
.
End Sub
```

Error gets thrown and highlights the first "Set" statement after the : (never gets to the Stop)

```
Public Function ParseJson(ByVal JsonString As String) As Object

Dim json_Index As Long
json_Index = 1

' Remove vbCr, vbLf, and vbTab from json_String
JsonString = VBA.Replace(VBA.Replace(VBA.Replace(JsonString, VBA.vbCr, ""), VBA.vbLf, ""), VBA.vbTab, "")

json_SkipSpaces JsonString, json_Index
Select Case VBA.Mid$(JsonString, json_Index, 1)
Case "{"
    Set ParseJson = json_ParseObject(JsonString, json_Index)
Case "["
    Set ParseJson = json_ParseArray(JsonString, json_Index)
Case Else
    ' Error: Invalid JSON string
    Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(JsonString, json_Index, "Expecting '{' or '['")
End Select
End Function
```

FYI

```
    http.response.text = ? http.responsetext
    {"meta":{"page":1,"per_page":25,"total_count":531,"total_pages":22},"data":[{"sales_tax":7.5,"total_untaxed":0.0,"discount_as_percentage":false,"discount":0.0,"customer_id":4902516,"user_id":37796,"orderstatus_id":185896,"public_hash":"a994d28ae3a530f53b0a62430e69","production_notes":"","order_nickname":"Augusta Shirts","approved":false,"approved_name":null,"visual_id":20535,"stats":{"paid":false},"notes":"","created_at":"2021-08-26T16:19:16.309-04:00","updated_at":"2021-08-29T15:09:56.930-04:00","due_date":"2021-08-26T10:00:00.000-04:00","order_total":71.0575,"order_subtotal":66.1,"payment_term_id":null,"delivery_method_id":null,"visual_po_number":"","customer":{"full_name":"James Wi","first_name":"James","last_name":"Wi","company":"","email":"xxxxx@gmail.com","customer_id":0},"order_addresses_attributes":[{"id":20803016,"name":"Customer Billing","customer_name":"James Wi","company_name":"","address1":"","address2":"","city":"","state":"","state_iso":null,"country":"US","country_iso":
    "US","zip":""},{"id":20803017,"name":"Customer Shipping","customer_name":"James Wi","company_name":"","address1":"","address2":"","city":"","state":"","state_iso":null,"country":"US","country_iso":"US","zip":""}],"contractor_profile":null,"expenses":[],"orderstatus":{"name":"Quote","color":"#47A0D9"},"user":{"name":"Chic"},"lineitems_attributes":[{"id":28200912,"style_description":"Augusta Sportswear - Adult Attain Wicking Short-Sleeve T-Shirt","taxable":true,"style_number":"2790","color":"Black","size_other":null,"size_xs":null,"size_s":null,"size_m":null,"size_l":null,"size_xl":null,"size_2xl":null,"size_3xl":3,"total_quantities":3,"goods_status":"","category":" 3-Apparel","unit_cost":115.66},{"id":28200913,"style_description":"Augusta Sportswear - Attain Color SecureÂ® Performance Long Sleeve T-Shirt","taxable":true,"style_number":"2795","color":"Black","size_other":null,"size_xs":null,"size_s":null,"size_m":null,"size_l":null,"size_xl":null,"size_2xl":null,"size_3xl":1,"total_quantities":1,"goods_stat
    us":"","category":" 3-Apparel","unit_cost":19.1},{"id":28200914,"style_description":"Sherriff","taxable":true,"style_number":"","color":"","size_other":1,"size_xs":null,"size_s":null,"size_m":null,"size_l":null,"size_xl":null,"size_2xl":null,"size_3xl":null,"total_quantities":1,"goods_status":"","category":" 2-Transfer Services","unit_cost":0.01},{"id":28200915,"style_description":"Franklin Badge","taxable":true,"style_number":"","color":"","size_other":1,"size_xs":null,"size_s":null,"size_m":null,"size_l":null,"size_xl":null,"size_2xl":null,"size_3xl":null,"total_quantities":1,"goods_status":"","category":" 1-Embroidery","unit_cost":0.01},{"id":28200916,"style_description":"","taxable":false,"style_number":"","color":"","size_other":null,"size_xs":null,"size_s":null,"size_m":null,"size_l":null,"size_xl":null,"size_2xl":null,"size_3xl":null,"total_quantities":0,"goods_status":"","category":"0-Convenience fee if paying by credit card","unit_cost":0.01}],"order_fees_attributes":[],"id":7161334,"customer_due_d
    ate":"2021-08-26T00:00:00.000-04:00","custom_created_at":"2021-08-26T00:00:00.000-04:00","invoice_date":"2021-08-26T00:00:00.000-04:00","payment_due_date":"2021-08-26T00:00:00.000-04:00","formatted_invoice_date":"08/26/2021","formatted_customer_due_date":"08/26/2021","formatted_payment_due_date":"08/26/2021","formatted_custom_created_at_date":"08/26/2021","url":"https://www.printavo.com/invoices/7161334","amount_paid":0.0,"amount_outstanding":71.0575,"public_url":"https://www.printavo.com/invoice/a995e8b4d28ae3a530f53b0a62430e69","pdf":"https://www.printavo.com/invoice/eff.pdf","workorder":"https://www.printavo.com/invoices/7/workorder","packaging_slip":"https://www.printavo.com/invoices/7/packing_slip"},{"sales_tax":0.0,"total_untaxed":0.0,"discount_as_percentage":false,"discount":0.0,"customer_id":99999,"user_id":9999,"orderstatus_id":196994,"public_hash":"eff","production_notes":"
    
    Order Notes:Â 
    Garments coming from XXXXXXX on
    PO XX99XX99XX99B:Â 
    
    TLJ763 Cornerstone Duck Cloth Work Jacket:Â 
    Navy: XLT-1, 2XLT-1Â 
    
    Garment coming from TrixXxXxXx on PO QQTTWWBBFFSS123456789A:Â 
    
    6000 Lightweight jacketÂ 
    Navy: 2XLT-1Â 
    
    Left chest, all garments: SDG Security logoÂ 
    Thread colors:Â 
    Red 1147, WhiteÂ 
    
Please let me know if you have any questions regarding the logo.Â 
    
I'll pick up when completed.Â 
    
 Thanks!

    ","order_nickname":"Prtewfgbvc5467843D -  security","approved":false,"approved_name":null,"visual_id":20534,"stats":{"paid":false,"paid_date":"2021-04-14"},"notes":"","created_at":"2021-08-26T15:49:00.048-04:00","updated_at":"2021-08-26T15:50:47.668-04:00","due_date":"2021-08-26T15:45:00.000-04:00","order_total":9.0,"order_subtotal":9.0,"payment_term_id":1817,"delivery_method_id":null,"visual_po_number":"P329D","customer":{"full_name":"Teresa L",
        .
        .
        .
        ]}
```

Comment: 1) Have you tried compiling the project and it compile without any error? 2) Is the module name `JsonConverter`?

Comment: Is `jsonconverter` module in same **project** as `getdata`? Are they both in **regular** modules? What is the name of the `jsonconverter` module?

Comment: You have declared an object `inJson` but are setting `Json`

Comment: @ Raymond - mod is in the same project.  will not compile - looking for json_ParseObject to be defined

Comment: @ron - both are in the same Project "VBAProject (Book1).  both are in regular modules. JsonConverter as shown in the Project viewer.  It was imported from JsonConverter.bas

Comment: @CDP - WOW!  thanks for the that!  fixed but still has the same error as a result

Comment: I think without examining your workbook and being able to reproduce your problem, we are all just guessing.  So far as `Dictionary.cls` is concerned, that is only needed if you will be running on a Mac. Since you have a windows machine, I suggest you remove that class module (one less source of potential confusion).  You can always re-import it if this project will be used on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is something in the response, probably the production_notes field. Try this simplified test program.

```vb
Sub test
    Dim inJson As Object, obj, s As String, msg As String
    s = "{'meta':{'page':1,'per_page':25,'total_count':531,'total_pages':22}}';"
    Set inJson = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)
    For Each obj In inJson("meta")
       msg = msg & obj & " : " & inJson("meta")(obj) & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox msg
end sub
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however, i got the same error; Compile error.  Sub or Function not defined

Comment: @Lee What is `Dictionary.cls` ?

Comment: instructions in JSON-VBA indicated I was to load this class into the project from github (Tim Hall version)

Comment: If you have added a reference to MS Runtime scripting you shouldn't need the Dictionary.cls, try removing it. Or are you wanting to use this on windows and Mac

Comment: @ CDP - created another project without the Dictionary Class.  Same error.  Where is json_ParseObject defined.  this seems to be the issue, right?  is it somewhere in JsonConverter?  couldn't find it...

Comment: Just found this line commented out in JsonConverter
'Private Function json_ParseObject(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As Dictionary

removed the comment and now getting Compile error, user defined type not defined.  
does that tell a different story about what I've messed up?

Comment: @Lee Don't edit the module, let's take this a step at a time. You have the latest version of JsonConvertor VBA-JSON-2.3.1 ? You have imported `JsonConverter.bas` into your project and added the reference to MIcrosoft Scripting Runtime and you can see JsonModule under Modules in Project Explorer. If you type `jsonconverter.` in the immediates window you should see a dropdown of method and properties. If you have notepad++ then `Private Function json_ParseObject` in on line 461 in `JsonConverter.bas` and is not commented out.

Comment: VICTORY.  that line (for whatever reason) was commented out.  fixed and all is good!.  MANY THANKS TO YOU!!

Comment: how can i give you credit for helping me?

Comment: @Lee You can accept my answer - see  https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer